# If statement does not works correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need some support. I am a newbie and I try to build a function which checks 2 entries in different sheets (both in one spreadsheet) if the condition "state" is true. If so the function has to set a value. If the condition is false, the function has to put a different value.

Currently the function set alway the same value (13:00) instead of the stored values.
I hope an one can help. Code below:

```
//Create an UI menu
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('⏰');

    ui.addItem(' Update ETAs','etaCheck')
    ui.addToUi();
}

function etaCheck(){

// Defined variabels
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ds = ss.getSheetByName('support ETA');
var ms = ss.getSheetByName('KPI Tracker 22');
var eta = ds.getRange('G2:G').getValues();
var tms1 = ds.getRange('E2:E').getValues();
var tms2 = ms.getRange('O2:O').getValues();
var state = ds.getRange('F2:F').getValues();


      // If statement
      if(tms1 === tms2 && state === 'Update'){
        ms.getRange('R2').setValue(eta)
      }else{
        ms.getRange('R2').setValue(eta)
      }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think the if statement doesn't work?

Comment: You have the same statement in your `if` and in your `else`. Whether your condition is true or false, you're doing the same thing.

Comment: Yes its true, because I have the states "Update" and "New". If the condition "Update" is true the eta will be set. If the condition is false so "New" the eta which is marked with "New" has to be stored.

Comment: Tms1 and tms2 are 2d arrays you need to iterate through them to check each row. Right now you are trying to compare the entire arrays and that does not work.

Comment: `state` is also a 2D array, so `state === 'Update'` also doesn't work that way (always results in `false`)

Comment: In order to help others better  understand what  the script should do, please add a sample input data and the corresponding result.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure but I think this is closer to what you desire

```
function etaCheck() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('support ETA');
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('KPI Tracker 22');
  const o = sh2.getRange(2, 18, sh2.getLastRow() - 1).getValues();
  const eta = sh1.getRange('G2:G' + sh1.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  const tms1 = sh1.getRange('E2:E' + sh1.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  const tms2 = sh2.getRange('O2:O' + sh2.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  const state = sh1.getRange('F2:F' + sh1.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  tms1.forEach((e,i) => {
    if(e == tms2[i] && state[i] == 'Update') {
      o[i][0] = eta[i]
      sh2.getRange(i + 2, 18).setValue(eta[i]);
    } else {
      sh2.getRange(i + 2, 18).setValue(eta[i]);//This does not make much sense since you are doing the same thing in both cases
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper, thank you for your input and sharing your code. It works but he is adding the data row by row instead of checking if the tms is also the same row. How I can fix this?

Comment: Try it now. I made a slight mod

Comment: Hi, still the same result.